Developing NFC-enabled app, but there is no NFC option in capabilities
Xcode is v15.2. iPhone 8. ios 15.0 is the deployment target. I have my iPhone 8 properly hooked to XCode, and I am doing development on it fine. However, for this app I need the NFC reading/writing capability. However, there is no options in Capabilities section (in Project name -> Target -> Signing & Capabilities -> +Capability) to add this. I tried creating .entitlements like so:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats</key>
    <array>
        <string>NDEF</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>

and still, the cap. is not there. How do I get this? I need this for my development. I don't have a paid Apple developer account.

Do you have a paid Apple developer membership?  The capability is listed as "near field communication tag reading"

This question is similar to: Developing NFC-enabled app, but there is no NFC option in capabilities. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
